# Why does warning shown in shell after eclipse run?

Tags: eclipse

WHen launching Eclipse in Shell, I get this warning:

```
(Eclipse:25663): Gtk-WARNING **: Negative content height -1 (allocation 1, extents 1x1) while allocating gadget (node scrolledwindow, owner GtkScrolledWindow)
```

How can I fix that please?

Answer (score 0):

The warning is shown in the shell because of [**Eclipse bug 533815**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533815) which has **already been fixed**.

Please upgrade to Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen many messages like that with Eclipse over the years.  They are generally harmless.

They typically occur while Eclipse is running.  You typically see them after Eclipse has exited because you had Eclipse maximized ... over the terminal window where the messages are displayed.

They are most likely due to a bug in Eclipse.

Solutions:

1. ignore them,
2. hide them by redirecting stderr to /dev/null,
3. search the Eclipse issue tracker, and see if there is a fix (e.g. upgrading),
4. if there is no existing issue, report it
5. find the bug, develop a fix / patch and submit it.